# Unit testing in silverlight and entity framework

Tags: silverlight

Could someone point me to any document, where I can test my silverlight application which uses entity framework as the backend data store? I found bunch links where they talk about only silveright UI testing not entity framework integration. One thing I am not able to do is, mock the data model that we use in silverlight that comes from entity frame work.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using RIA services, you can test your service with the regular .net unit testing framework or nunit

And then you you can unit test your UI using the [silverlight unit testing framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) against your view model

Comment: Thanks, I found this link http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-ViewModel-Pattern-2.aspx most useful for anyone using SL4 +RIA services for their testing.